# Is this notation for an inner product common?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, notation, inner-products

In my measure theory and integration course we learned about line integrals and surface integrals. My lecturer uses the notation $(u | v)_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ to denote the (Euclidean) dot product of two vectors $u, v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is a notation that I have never seen before except for the books of Daniel Stroock on integration (books that my lecturer mentioned and recommended to us-otherwise I would have never heard of these books since I don't think they are that popular, but I may be wrong since I am a novice when it comes to measure, integration and related aspects). This means that if we, say, integrate some function $F$ on some space curve $\sigma$, then the notation used would be $$\int_{\sigma} (F|dl)_{\mathbb{R}^3}$$ due tot the way we denote the dot product.
Needless to say that in any online resource (and any books I have) this is not the way to denote things.
So, is this notation popular or is it some weird one used by only a handful of people? My hunch is that it is common in certain areas of mathematics (I suspect PDEs/functional analysis because this is my lecturer's research field, but I haven't taken any course on either of those subjects, so I really can't say if my hunch is correct) and certainly not at the basic level (i.e. a regular multivariable calculus class let's say), this being the reason that it seemed weird to me.

Comment: It is not especially common, but it is not weird.

Comment: Indeed not common. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366070/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-vector-inner-products-as-langle-u-v-rangle/366118

Comment: I would say the notation comes more from physics, quite related to the bra- and -ket.

Comment: Actually, I have already seen this notation a couple of times, so i don't find it weird at all. In fact, in my first higher dimensional analysis classes we always denoted the line integrals like that...

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, I realize now that weird may have been a tad too strong. I think that I wanted that weird to mean uncommon.

Comment: @TedShifrin interesting, thank you! I hadn't heard about this since I am not into physics, but I see that this bra-ket notation seems to be a good reason to go for this notation for inner products.

Comment: @G.Blaickner yeah, I do realize that I should have said uncommon instead of weird. I am glad that it is not such a strange notation after all since other people also use it :).

Comment: It is not uncommon, but best avoided, in my opinion. I believe the only reason it is used is to avoid having to write `\langle` and `\rangle` over and over again, but with the new command declaration utilities of Latex this really is a non issue.

Comment: To expand on K.defaoite's comment, one _Should_ code LaTeX semantically, introducing a macro such as `\IP{u}{v}`. Doing so saves keystrokes, is less error-prone, and allows one's code to be adjusted to a house style by changing _one instance_ in the preamble, without editing however many dozens of instances in the document body.